# Ding ding I'm on the tram

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions, british-english

My dad would say this if I helped myself to something with out offering him any. Such as a cup of coffee. Is this an English phrase?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a common phrase.  Google yields no results, nor does a search of historical newspapers or other corpora that I checked.

Comment: Was your dad English? Knowing where he was from might help identify if it's a regional phrase.

Comment: It doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: Apparently, "ding ding" is the nickname used for Hong Kong trams http://averagetraveller.com/hong-kong-tramways-ride-on-the-ding-ding/3945/ and https://www.tripadvisor.fr/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g294217-d1992541-i40064170-Hong_Kong_Tramways_Ding_Ding-Hong_Kong.html

Answer (score 3):

A similar phrase was "I'm on the bus ding, ding". Explanation - On a bus in the 1950s and before passengers, or the bus conductor, pressed the bell once to stop it and twice to tell the driver to proceed. The phrase therefore meant you rang as you were on the bus so it could set off even if there were others behind you wanting to get on. In other words 'I'm OK but hard luck to those behind as I don't care for your predicament'. Therefore not that dissimilar to 'I'm alright Jack!'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A good answer. But on SE answers need to quote some supporting reference . Try adding some links.

Comment: I confirm from personal experience that the same practice was followed on trams in Melbourne (Australia) until conductors were phased out in the 1990s.

Comment: Here's an [example on Mumsnet](https://www.mumsnet.com/talk/relationships/595275-how-can-i-tell-my-mum-i-dont-want-to) (with explanation).

Comment: So in OP's example, dad is putting words into Ceri's mouth, showing his (then) selfish attitude.